# Error when passing string through

Tags: c++, model

This is my code:

```
#include "animal.h"

Animal::Animal(string animal)
{
    this->animal = animal;
}

string Animal::toString()
{
    return animal;
}

Animal newInstance(string animal)
{
   return new Animal(animal); // HERE IS THE ERROR
}
```

In my header:

```
private:
    string animal;
```

> error: could not convert '(std::basic_string((*(const
>   std::basic_string*)(& animal))), (operator new(8u),
>   (, ((Animal*)))))' from 'Animal*' to
>   'Animal'

Also I the `newInstance` method is needed, I should not need to remove it.

Comment: `new` is a rarely used thing in (modern) C++.

Comment: @chris really?? I did not know that, I'm coming to c++ from Java/Python. How would you go about doing the newInstance method?

Comment: You'd normally create one on the stack when possible with `Animal(animal)` to be explicit or just `return animal;` if that converting constructor is implicit. If you absolutely need free store memory, use a smart pointer. C++ doesn't have a garbage collector to clean up after your `new`s whenever it feels like getting around to it. Really, though, the function call is longer to type than just creating the object, and adds another layer of indirection that people have to look through to see for sure what the code is doing.

Comment: This has nothing whatsoever to do with "passing string through".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the mistake, the return type of your `newInstance` function should be a pointer to `Animal`:

```
Animal *newInstance(string animal) // Note the '*'
{
   return new Animal(animal);
}
```

Or, as @chris suggested, `new` is indeed rarely used in modern C++, you would need to use smart pointers, for example with an `std::shared_ptr`:

```
#include <memory>

std::shared_ptr<Animal> newInstance(string animal)
{
   return std::make_shared<Animal>(animal);
}
```

Or you could return a value, then you should remove the `new`:

```
Animal newInstance(string animal)
{
   return Animal(animal);
}
```